# Javascript - Issue on event listeners of classList

Tags: javascript

I have a "+" button that , when clicked, triggers the creation of a block with an input and 2 buttons, one for validating the input and one for removing it.

[image]

// My code looks almost like this :

```
    addBtn.addEventListener('click', e => {
        addClick++;

// All the elements of the same line (input and 2 buttons) have an int in common in their id string ==> addClick 

// I'm missing all the declarations of the variables here
    blockDiv.appendChild(posteInput);
    blockDiv.appendChild(validateBtn);
    blockDiv.appendChild(deleteBtn);
    globalPostesBlock.appendChild(blockDiv)

    let allDeleteBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('delete-button');

        for (let i = 0; i < allDeleteBtn.length; i++) {

            allDeleteBtn[i].addEventListener('click', e => {

                    // Retrieving the block with the same id
                    let deleteBtnId = parseInt((allDeleteBtn[i].getAttribute('id').match(/\d+/g)).toString());
                    let singlePosteBlock = document.getElementById(`poste-block-${deleteBtnId}`);
                    singlePosteBlock.remove();
                }

            })
        }
```

The event listener represents the action of clicking the delete button so it can remove its entire containing block

I have the same logic for the validate button, but I'm using ajax in it.

Each time I create a new block, I want to create an event listener associated to this block, but all I found so far is an event listener with a loop on every buttons, so what happens is that **the action triggers as many time as the block numbers because of the loop**, but I don't know how to dissociate every event listeners.

If I have 3 blocks and I validate one input value which is being inserted in the DB afterwards, the value is being inserted 3 times.

Comment: You can add the event listener to `deleteBtn` (the newly created button) instead of all the buttons.

Comment: `parseInt((allDeleteBtn[i].getAttribute('id').match(/\d+/g)).toString())` can probably be replaced by `allDeleteBtn[i].id.match(/\d+/)[0]`.

Comment: @Titus As simple as that ! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help ?

```js
//id pool
let latestId = 0;

//retrive the button
var myButton = document.querySelector("button");

myButton.addEventListener("click", createKids);

//function declaration :: createKids
function createKids() {
  latestId++;
  //declare and initialization
  let div = document.createElement("div");
  let input = document.createElement("input");
  let buttonSend = document.createElement("button");
  let buttonDelete = document.createElement("button");

  //append input & buttons to div
  div.appendChild(input);
  div.appendChild(buttonSend);
  div.appendChild(buttonDelete);

  //Some beautifying
  buttonSend.innerText = "Send me";
  buttonDelete.innerText = "Delete me";

  //some logic
  div.dataset.id = latestId;

  //event handeling
  buttonSend.addEventListener("click", sendItem);
  buttonDelete.addEventListener("click", deleteItem);

  //insert div
  document.body.appendChild(div);
}

function sendItem(event) {
  //do action and delete ?
  let input = event.target.parentNode.querySelector("input");


  //retrive data
  let val = input.value;
  let id = event.target.parentNode.dataset.id;
  
  //disable input for fun ^^
  input.disabled = true;
  
  //console istead of send 
  console.log(id,val);

  //handle some more
  setTimeout(() => {
    event.target.parentNode.remove();
  }, 3000);
}

function deleteItem(event) {
  event.currentTarget.parentNode.remove();
}
```

```html
<p>Does this help?</p>
<button>Magic Button</button>
```

Comment: It does the trick too, but as answered under my question, putting the event listener on the newly created button did the trick, But I'll mark this as accepted since it works too

Comment: @naspy971 yeah that was the thing is was trying to point out, thank you for accepting my answer, feel free to ask if needed.